Prove that at least two people shake hands the same number of times
There are $n$ people in a party. Any of them can shake hands with any other, any number of times. We need to prove (or disprove) that at least $2$ people do equal number of handshakes.
Note that any given pair can have multiple handshakes too! So we can't directly apply PHP here since the number of handshakes is unbounded.
I got this problem in my head while solving the original problem which uses a direct application of PHP. I am since not able to solve this problem. (The statement seems correct only, not able to find a counter example till now)

Just as I post this, and this pops up in my head:
(1,1,2,2) (this is a valid combination of handshakes for the unique case)
Now, we add (0,1,0,1) (handshake of 2nd and 4th person)
and (0,0,1,1) (handshake of 3rd and 4th) to get (1,2,3,4), so the statement is wrong.

Construct a graph where the people are the nodes and the handshakes are the edges. Then we have (at least) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma .

This is pure pigeonhole and induction. If somebody shakes no hands, we can remove them and this reduces to the $n-1$ case . Otherwise, you have $n$ people and they each shake hands $1$ to $n-1$ times.

@ThomasAndrews The problem allows two people to shake hands repeatedly, counting each shake.  With three people you could have $A,B$ shake hands ten times and $B,C$ once, breaking equality.

If a loopless multi-graph is constructed where people are nodes and handshakes are edges, this is a matter of constructing degree se
quences of (connected) graphs, see e.g. the PostScript file in https://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/AlleyCat/AlleyCat.html. https://oeis.org/A147878 contains examples of degree sequences where some degrees appear only once.

Just as I posted this, this popped up in my head:
$(1,1,2,2)$ --> this is a valid combination of handshakes for the unique case.
Now, we add $(0,1,0,1)$ --> handshake of 2nd and 4th person and,
$(0,0,1,1)$ --> handshake of 3rd and 4th to get:
$(1,2,3,4)$, so the statement is wrong.

Yes, it's even possible with just three people to get $(1,2,3)$.
